# PYQT call a function on a button, with a file selected

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to create a gui file convertor.  I want to select which file to convert and use my function that converts on the file.

```
 class Window(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

    self.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)

    self.setWindowTitle("Convert XML to CSV!")

# Open a FILE and append to screen
    self.buttonSelect = QtGui.QPushButton('Select Files', self)
    self.buttonSelect.move(350, 100)
    self.buttonSelect.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)


    self.buttonConvert = QtGui.QPushButton('Convert', self)
    self.buttonConvert.move(50,100)
    self.buttonConvert.setFixedSize(155,100)
    self.buttonConvert.clicked.connect(self.convert)

def handleButton(self):
    title = self.buttonSelect.text()
    file_list = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, title)
    for path in file_list:
        print (path)
    self.fileList = file_list
    self.askForfFile.setText(path)

    return file_list
```

## ---------------

```
def convertor(self):
 # process all non-master CSVs
    for fileLocated in os.listdir(directoryPath):
        if fileLocated.endswith(".csv") and 'master' not in fileLocated.lower():

            csvFilename = fileLocated

   etc..
```

Any help would be appreciated or coaching!  yes spacing is off due to tab not working in browser :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not quite sure if this is your problem:
`QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, title)` returns a tuple with the list of selected files with their full path and the filter resp. an empty string if no filter is set. So you have to iterate over `file_list[0]` to get the selected files. If you set a filter at this place the user only can select files matching the filter:

```
file_list = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, title, None, 'CSV-files: *.csv')   
for path in file_list[0]:
    ....
```